# Explanation for this type of (magic-trick) suspension?

Tags: forces, levitation

Well let's start off with that I'm not a physicist but I'd like some thoughts on something I came across in my hometown.

This guy:

[image]

Is it possible that due to the electrical charge of magnets this guy can make the illusion that he can float ? Or is this probably a cheap trick that fools the eye ? I was standing there for quite some time watching the guy and he keep moving his feet. The resistance that he appeared to have was from a magnet force keeping him afloat. So after I passed this guy I did some physics searches on the web and the first thing that caught my eye was the electrical charge of magnets.

So the question is : Is this related to the electrical charge of a magnet or a cheap trick ?

Comment: what if this is a photo-montage, this guy looks like a statue, so probably this is pure mechanics and strength of materials involved

Comment: lest your question be downvoted (some people actually do that), i would recommend to rephrase it to sth more tangible

Comment: The photo is not a montage cause I took it myself :) I would not post forged images on here just for fun .. And why the change ? It's my working theory that involves electrical charge of magnets to accomplish this.

Comment: well strong electromagnetic fields can certainly achieve this (as easily as they can lift a heavy-ton train to incredible speeds). The question is: is this actually done using electromagnetism or not? And unfortunately one cannot answer this from a picture even if it is yours.

Comment: I cannot see how we could answer that. I've seen these guys myself, but it is a magician's trick - not a well documented phenomenon of nature.

Comment: let me give you a youtube link to a yogi that does sth similar (and then explains how) :), give me a couple of minutes to find it

Comment: here it is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FzNyc0I_w_M, go to around 27:00

Comment: @ACuriousMind, magician's tricks are phenomena of nature (documented or not is another matter). Quoting Poincare on the Michelson-Morley experiment. "It is as if nature conspires for the MM experiment to fail". Poincare: "Then this is a law of nature". See how simple it is?

Comment: I don't think the answer lies in a steel bar and a seat as he is standing up ..

Comment: Yes, but it shows the principle of operation, untill the yogi stood up you would not see it. i didnt say it would be the same, i said it would be similar. Btw search for levitation tricks, this trick is in that area

Comment: See how the guy holds a long stick. Why? Pure electromagnetism would not require that (or at least would make it look way more surreal)

Comment: i think we (against all odds) managed to answer the question. The stick is the answer

Comment: Someone said it is a talent of a researcher to ask "why"

Comment: I hope you tipped him! If a street busker makes you stop what you're doing and admire, you owe him at least a dollar.

Comment: Would [skeptics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think so. What's the *notable* claim here? The single opinion of the OP cannot be considered as a *notable* claim.

Comment: Ofcourse i tipped the guy :) But like I said I'm not a physicist so the movement of his feet intriged me to look this up how that they did it and the movement of his feet made me think of magnetism

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about *guessing* how a magician's trick works.

Comment: I don't want to be rude @ACuriousMind but your nickname suggests u have a curious mind... And how I saw it , I thought it involved magnetism. So I don't see why I can't ask a question that might be off-topic because I thought it involved magnetism? So I can't be curious minded and endeavor to find the answer to my question ?

Comment: Please understand that close votes are not personal. I am not saying you cannot be interested in how this trick works (I'm a bit intrigued by it myself). I am not saying you should stop trying to find answers to your questions (you shouldn't). But this *specific question* does, in my view, not belong on this *specific site*, as I don't see a *physical* explanation arising. And I feel justified in that since the top answer at the moment is probably right but enlightens no one about a bit of *actual physics*.

Comment: Well I got my answer so it's not physics like I thought it was. But the reason that I thought it involved magnetism is the reason I posted here :)

Comment: Leuven on the Grote Markt

Comment: @ACuriousMind, leaving aside the fact of the avatar name ("Curious Mind"), this question has an (accepted and highly voted by memebrs of this site) answer. is it about physics? i will say yes!!! Why? Because, at the very least, the question asks for a physical explanation and indeed one was provided (and backed up with facts and physical reasoning).

Comment: To all those that closed this question. There is a very serious issue here. People that accepted and up-voted the question and the answers  (of course, members of this site) are an order of magnitude more than those who closed this question. This poses a very serious issue here (and elsewhere on similar cases). @DavidZ, since you are moderator (but comemnt involves everyone here)

Comment: @NikosM. no, this is not a serious issue because upvotes don't determine whether a question is on topic. Questions are on or off topic regardless of how many people upvote them. Indeed, historically off-topic questions tend to be some of the highest voted ones. Also, not that this is particularly relevant, but keep in mind that the number of people with the ability to vote on the question is more than two orders of magnitude more than those with the ability to cast close votes. (Also I've removed the unnecessary emphasis from your comments.)

Comment: I would add that the mere fact that a question asks for a physical explanation of something does not, in my view, make it on topic here. I don't know that we have any explicit policy on that matter though. Perhaps it would be a good thing to discuss in [chat] or on [meta].

Comment: @DavidZ, i certainly agree that this needs attention and discussion. A final comment though, certainly all those members of this site who upvoted the answers and question do not consider this to be off-topic and still poses an issue. We cannot turn this into a chat, but lets note for later

Comment: @DavidZ, posted in [meta about this issue here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6075/44176)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The "trick" is that the cane he is apparently holding is actually firmly attached to the platform.  A rigid piece goes up his sleave, then to a harness that holds his whole body up.  For more about this type of magic trick device, google "broom suspension" or "aerial suspension harness".

No electric or magnetic fields were abused here.

[image: Image Credit: TwentyTwoWords]
*<sub>Image Credit: [TwentyTwoWords](http://twentytwowords.com/2-street-performers-take-levitation-to-a-whole-new-level/)</sub>*

Comment: Very clear explanation. If you look closely at the photo in the question you can see that the cane is bending...

Comment: check out this video here, which shows a performer setting the trick up. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwvYkRzpq4g

Comment: You can run, Olin, but you can't hide. A hit squad from the Magic Circle has been despatched.

Comment: maybe the discussion about the closing of this question will interest you [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6075/44176)

Comment: @NikosM. - it certainly did: thanks for pointing it out. I have posted a response.

Comment: thanx Floris, seen it and kudos. It is nice seeing other people taking a stand there

Answer (score 23):

Olin Lanthrop clearly gave the most plausible explanation. But just for fun, let's just assume this was an electromagnetic trick. Would that be possible?

First - let's do this using electrical charge: how much charge would you need to allow levitation, and what would the potential have to be?

Some assumptions:

```
70 kg guy
40 cm levitation (based on apparent height)
equal charges
cane is perfect insulator
```

The force needed would be about 700N; solving

$$F=\frac{Q^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}$$
gives
$$Q = r\sqrt{4\pi\epsilon_0 F}$$
and
$$V = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r} \approx 3.5 MV$$

If I did not make a mistake, this makes the voltage on both the performer and the platform above which he is hovering about 3.5 MV. Note that this value is independent of the height he is hovering... just the force required. The breakdown voltage of atmospheric air depends on many factors - but you're not going to hold 3.5 MV on an irregularly shaped object without some serious corona discharge - the electrical breakdown strength of air is around $3.6\cdot10^6 V/m$, which will easily be exceeded in this configuration. I conclude **it cannot be static electricity** holding him up.

So, **could it be magnetism**?

With magnetic levitation, there are two problems: the strength of the magnet, and stability (two dipoles cannot provide a stable levitation platform). Let's tackle the stability by making the platform is a superconductor; then the "magnetic pressure" is

$$P_{mag}=\frac{B^2}{2\mu_0}$$

Because I don't want to do the integral, I am going to assume that the field is uniform over a diameter equal to the distance; then we can compute the force:

$$F = P\cdot A = \frac{B^2 \pi d^2 / 4}{2\mu_0}\\
= \frac{B^2 \pi d^2 }{8\cdot 4\pi 10^{-7}}\\
= \frac{B^2 0.16 }{32\cdot 10^{-7}}$$

Setting to 700N and solving for $B$:

$$B = \sqrt{700 \cdot 200 \cdot 10^{-7}}\\
= 0.12 T$$

In principle it is possible to make permanent magnets that strong... but they would weigh quite a bit more than 70 kg (meaning you would have to update this calculation), and you wouldn't want to walk around with them on the market square of Leuven. Oh - and there's the minor problem of the cryogenics needed for your superconducting platform...

Comment: So if I understand this correctly the magnets would have a mass more then 70kg to achieve levitation through magnets ?

Comment: @NicolasPierre - I did not compute that, but to maintain a field of 0.1 T at a distance of 40 cm (as opposed to "at the surface") you need quite a large magnet, as a dipole field falls off with $r^3$; when you have a large area, you operate in the "near field" region of the magnet so it will drop off more slowly. So while it's possible to have a smaller magnet (e.g. Neodymium) with a quoted strength of 0.1T, it would not work in this situation.

Comment: If you added an electromagnet (which would only need to provide a small portion of the levitation) and a PID controller then minor adjustments could constantly be made to the force stabilising the whole thing: this would remove the requirements for superconducting

Comment: @RichardTingle - you sound like you are reading a draft answer that I wrote but edited before posting... yes you can use active electromagnets to stabilize the levitation - then you need permanent magnets in both the feet and the platform below. Given the need to support lateral force on the feet the demands on the servo system would be not inconsiderable. A good project for an engineering Master's thesis, maybe?

Comment: I think you're being over-hasty in rejecting the magnetism hypothesis. His cryogenic kit is in the sewers: the purpose of his little "stage" is to conceal the open manhole cover.  The "cane" is used to pipe coolant to the magnet on his body. Easy when you know how. ;-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I see... And this clever fellow invented a silent cryo cooler which can run off a portable power supply . Must be galling to be _that_ talented and still end up begging for pennies in the market square... There is no justice in this world.

Comment: maybe the discussion about the closing of this question will interest you [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6075/44176)

Comment: I disagree with @DavidRicherby. I haven't calculated, but I suppose the investment in setting up that sort of a thing far exceeds the money a person can potentially make in a day or two by begging. And you are not sure whether or not you will make money. But, what you mean to say is - it is not impossible, and I agree. But realistic? I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 2):

Spiders can fly by charging a piece of web and using the 120 V/m field to go up.

But i suspect that for a human-size weight, one would need too big of a charge to use electrostatic forces, and such would discharge through the air.

Comment: is this from spiderman? i am kidding of course, but i think the mechanics of how spiders jump was on an early spiderman volume

Comment: And how does this answer the question?

Comment: maybe the discussion about the closing of this question will interest you [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6075/44176)